# Connecting a DB2 database from a Webserver in PHP Wordpress

Tags: php, db2, ibm-midrange

We have got a website that has been written in PHP (Wordpress)
It is running on a VPS that has got the DB2 module installed. 
But we are unable to get the website connecting with the DB2 database that is on the I5 (AS400) server to be able to preform SQL statements.
Currently the website we have got that is connected is in .asp and the person who did all that is no longer here.

I came across this article 
[Connect PHP to AS400 with ODBC or DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24087322/)
Which is a bit of a help.
But does anyone have some instuctions or step by step information about setting this up on the I5 (AS400) server and the website on the webserver. I have come across a IBM product call DB2 connect is this what I need.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Are you saying to install IBM i Access for Windows on to the Webserver?

Comment: I have IBM i Access for Windows installed on my PC that I connect to my Iseries now and use the emulator to connect from my PC to my ISeries

Comment: I want to be able to connect from the VPS webserver (my website in PHP wordpress ) to the As400 DB2 database.

Comment: Yes.  Install Client Access on the VPS web server.  You don't need the full install; only the ODBC drivers.

Comment: I assume the VPS is using a Windows-based operating system? The instructions Buck has given you will work fine for Windows but it's different for Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 versions of DB2: DB2 for Linux, Unix, Windows; DB2 for Z (mainframe); DB2 for IBM i.  The machine you are calling i5 or AS/400 is running the IBM i operating system.  The typical DB2 ODBC driver is probably for DB2 LUW.  You want toe ODBC drivers for IBM i.  These come with the product called [IBM i Access for Windows](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaij/rzaijpccheck.htm?lang=en).  In earlier years, it was called Client Access for Windows.

The installer is on a DVD.  The installation image is also on the IBM i server.

- Map a network drive to QIBM\ProdData\Access\Windows on your IBM i.
- Double-click cwblaunch.exe
- Use the wizard to complete the install.

You can select to install only the ODBC driver by choosing 'Custom' install.